# mod_firehose for Apache 2.2?

Tags: apache-2.2, https

Can [mod_firehose](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_firehose.html) be made to work with Apache 2.2, or can its functionality be got in some other way?

We need to record https traffic for Apache 2.2 (on a Windows 7 box) in exactly the way mod_firehose does, i.e. on the plain text side of SSL connections. Wireshark can dissect SSL traffic if it is given the keys, but without further processing its output is a long way from that of the firehose.

The Apache site doesn't list mod_firehose for Apache 2.2, and the description of mod_firehose suggests that Apache 2.5+ is required...

P.S.: as a temporary measure we enabled logging via [mod_dumpio](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dumpio.html), which dumps everything into the error log. This is better than nothing at all, but because of the obvious disadvantages we'd very much like the functionality of mod_firehose...

Comment: How much programming do you want to do?

Comment: @ Michael Hampton: I'd be willing to invest on the order of one or two afternoons - but my knowledge of Apache is restricted to what I've learnt today, so I'm probably not much use. If 2.4 had mod_firehose then I'd try migrating to that, but I'm somewhat loath to migrate a production service to the 2.5 development branch just for the firehose... I'm currently exploring ways of extracting a firehose-like stream from Wireshark captures (after feeding it the SSL key) but it does seem rather involved - and it makes a mod_firehose pipe look very nice indeed in comparison.

Comment: I thought you said this was Apache on Windows 7? How did an obviously non-production stack get into production?